# Access tab-separated rows with quoted fields containing newlines and more quotes

Tags: python, csv, tabular

I have a long file with rows ending in newlines, and fields separated by tabs. Fields are quoted using "". A single quoted field may also contain newlines, and -- as an added twist -- may additionally contain quoted strings.

Here is an example illustrating all cases:

```
"FieldA"    "FieldB"    "FieldC"
"AnotherOne"    "May contain
newlines"   "FieldC"
"Here is one more row"  "FieldB"    "FieldC"
"And here is a twist"   "Some fields with newlines may contain or end with "quotes and"
continue on next line"  "FieldC"
```

I tried csv module in this way:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as csvfile:
    a = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    for row in a:
        print len(row)
```

...but this gives me variable row lenghts, so I cannot access a field reliably. How to access values in such a file reliably from Python?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a reliable way to parse fields that contain the same kind of quote characters that are used as delimiters, unless you have additional information about the file structure.  How would you, as a human, decide in a rigorous way where the field ends in such a case (like your field beginning with "Some fields...")?

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn. As a human I think I would know that the field ends when I encounter a quote char followed by a tab or -- if a sufficient number of fields have been found already in this row -- followed by a newline. I just don't know if there is an established way of handling this in Python.